# Sails.js + Grunt: recompile assets

Tags: node.js, gruntjs, assets, sails.js

I deleted my js files in the .tmp folder. Now none of the js files get recompiled on `sails lift`. All of the needed JS files are included in the `Gruntfile.js` like this:

```
var jsFilesToInject = [

// Below, as a demonstration, you'll see the built-in dependencies 
// linked in the proper order order

// Bring in the socket.io client
'linker/js/socket.io.js',

// then beef it up with some convenience logic for talking to Sails.js
'linker/js/sails.io.js',

// A simpler boilerplate library for getting you up and running w/ an
// automatic listener for incoming messages from Socket.io.
'linker/js/app.js',

// *->    put other dependencies here   <-*
'linker/js/jquery.min.js',
'linker/js/index.js',

// All of the rest of your app scripts imported here
'linker/**/*.js'
];
```

And also put script includes in the end of the `layout.ejs`.

I'm new to node.js, sails.js, Grunt and to this whole asset management thing. I've some similar questions on Stackoverflow, but with no answers.

Comment: What version of Sails are you using?

Comment: @ScottGress, version: 0.9.9

Comment: Are your assets saved in the `/assets/linker` folder?  Only those assets will be copied by Grunt by default in v0.9.x.

Comment: Yes. All assets are in assets/linker. It works weird, very inconsistent. Sometimes it copies the assets into public folder, sometimes it does not. As a workaround, I just copy it myself.

Comment: What happens when you run `grunt`?